# Java : For String values we use the command sendKeys("String"); Similarly what is the command for posting a numeric data to the numeric field

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Selenium Java Web Driver: How to pass numeric data to a numeric field?
For `String` values we use the command `sendKeys("String");`. Similarly, what is the command for posting numeric data to the numeric field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do `sendKeys("9");` it will send the number to the numeric field. I suppose you have something like that:

```
 int numberToSend = 9;
```

And you want to send it to numeric field. You can do it by these two ways:

```
String numberToString = "" + numberToSend;
```

And then you can use either

```
webElement.sendKeys(""+numberToSend);
```

or

```
webElement.sendKeys(numberToString);
```

Comment: Thanks Pavel Janicek. Its Working.

Comment: Note that the most preferred way to produce a `String` out of an `int` in Java is [`String.valueOf(numberToSend)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) or [`Integer.toString(numberToSend)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29)

Comment: @ani dont forget to say thank you by accepting answer as correct one.

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

```
String s = "24";
Integer s1 = Integer.parseInt(s);
String orderPercent = s1.toString();
.sendKeys(orderPercent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting  that integer to string is the simple and easy solution, like this:

```
int i=1;
String A = Integer.toString(i);
```

Now pass the value to sendkeys like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(A);
```

And it will send the value `1`.