# I am not able to retain numeric values in numeric fields using Java in Webdriver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to retain numeric values in numeric fields using Java in Webdriver. I have tried the answer provided in Stackoverfolw question -

[Java : For String values we use the command sendKeys("String"); Similarly what is the command for posting a numeric data to the numeric field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224822/java-for-string-values-we-use-the-command-sendkeysstring-similarly-what-i/14152347#14152347)

Please find the more details in the answer section i have written.

```
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).sendKeys(String.valueOf(12345));
Thread.sleep(5000);
new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))), 
"").perform();
```

This is one field,like wise i have more numeric fields. Can anyone help me out on this issue. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sending integer value to integer field is same as sending text value to text field.

```
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).sendKeys("12345");
```

OR

If you have any integer value saved in variable

```
int value=12345;
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).sendKeys(""+value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried this one earlier itself before posting this question. It is not working.

Comment: Whats happening If you do the same thing like above? any exception? 
Whats the actual problem with integer fields?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The value sent is clears automatically and doesnot save the value in the field. There is no exception displayed.

Comment: How could it be possible? Make sure that you are not calling clear() method on the same locator after sending keys.

Post your code here.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. please find the code below.   driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccName_Id"))).clear();
  driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccName_Id"))).sendKeys(AccName+"_"+Randnum);
  driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccDBA_ID"))).sendKeys("Kumar_DBA");
  driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).sendKeys(""+numberToSend);
  Thread.sleep(5000);
  new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))), "").perform();
  driver.findElement(By.name(OR.getProperty("AccAddress_ID"))).sendKeys("124 - City Cross Roads");

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"))).sendKeys("00501");
  new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccZip_ID"))), "").perform();

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Thread.sleep();`

First You have to enable the element. Then put the value on that field.

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).click();
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).sendKeys(String.valueOf(12345));
driver.findElement(By.id(OR.getProperty("AccTax_ID"))).sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
```